# RenderPartialAsync returns System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET 5 RC1

`_MyPartial`

```
@model MyViewModel

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                @Html.MyHtmlHelperRow(model => model.ShortDistrictName)
                @Html.MyHtmlHelperRowSaveButton(model => model.Id)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

`cshtml` View

```
@model MyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MyPartial", Model)

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

the line

```
@Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MyPartial", Model)
```

apart from it rendering in html,  renders

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]
```

text in the html directly below the last content rendered by the partial page.

If I change the partial line reference to non async

```
@Html.Partial("_MyPartial", Model)
```

then I don't get this text line.

Questions:

1. Why do I get the text line in my html
2. How do I get rid of it and still be able to use RenderPartialAsync?

Comment: use the `await` key word, it should work, like it's done in the @section Scripts  @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MyPartial", Model); }

Comment: use partialasync method with @await Html.PartialAsync("_Edit",Model.EditCommand), curly braces are not required

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use `await` to call asynchronous methods. ASP.NET 5 adds the ability to use `await` in Razor:

```
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_MyPartial", Model);}
```

Answer (score 9):

using the syntax in the accepted answer gave me this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
>
> @await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ProductList", Model)

in RC1 I had to use curly braces and a semicolon:

```
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ProductList", Model);}
```

`RenderPartialAsync` writes directly to the response and returns void (technically Task), which the view compiler can't print as a string.

Comment: There may have been some changes between November and March, but it looks like in the official release, this is the way to do it.

Comment: use partialasync method with  @await Html.PartialAsync("_Edit",Model.EditCommand), curly braces are not required